# How to draw a vertical line on specific day in TradingView pine script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I've no experience in coding in pine script but I'd like to modified the script to draw a vertical line on Tuesday and Wednesday based on the code below.

```
//@version=4
study("Tuesday/Wednesday/Week Breaks", shorttitle="Tue/Wed/Day/Week breaks", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

// workaround to apply this indicator to another indicator
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)

is_new(resolution) =>
    t = time(resolution)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])

is_new_week() =>
    is_new('W')

is_new_day() =>
    is_new("D")

is_new_tuesday() =>
    is_new("Tuesday")

is_new_wednesday() =>
    is_new("Wednesday")

// plotting
plot(is_new_day() ? 1 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), title='Day breaks')
plot(is_new_tuesday() ? 1 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), title='Tuesday breaks')
plot(is_new_wednesday() ? 1 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), title='Wednesday breaks')
plot(is_new_week() ? 1 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.green, 50), title='Week breaks')
```

I tried to add is_new_tuesday() and is_new_wednesday() but it couldn't work as intended, I couldn't figure out how the is_new(resolution) function

```
is_new_tuesday() =>
    is_new("Tuesday")

is_new_wednesday() =>
    is_new("Wednesday")

plot(is_new_tuesday() ? 1 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), title='Tuesday breaks')
plot(is_new_wednesday() ? 1 : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), title='Wednesday breaks')
```

Answer (score 0):

That `is_new()` functions expects a [timeframe](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Timeframes.html?highlight=timeframe#timeframe-string-specifications). You cannot just randomly pass strings like "Tuesday".

You can use the built-in variable `dayofweek` to figure out if it is a new Tuesday and then draw your line.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_new_tuesday = (dayofweek[1] != dayofweek.tuesday) and (dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday)

if (is_new_tuesday)
    line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index, high + syminfo.mintick, extend=extend.both)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, I tried to integrate the code you provided, but I got compilation error. Is there a solution to integrate built-in variable `dayofweek` into existing code?

Comment: Upgrade your code to v5. Why are you using v4 anyway?

Comment: I copied the code from another public published code on Trading View and it's still supporting v4